# How can I reliably determine the available space left in a MySQL database?

Tags: mysql

We are developing a Joomla component that takes up a lot of database space and would like to make sure that the user have enough space before completing the installation.

After some testing it appears that the following code is recommended but when testing on a SiteGround.com server it returned that there was not enough space when when there was.

```
SELECT table_schema "Data Base Name", 
sum( data_length + index_length ) / 1024 / 1024 "Data Base Size in MB", 
sum( data_free )/ 1024 / 1024 "Free Space in MB" 
FROM information_schema.TABLES 
GROUP BY table_schema;
```

Since at least some hosting providers do not properly support this method, is there another way we can test this or is there a way we can test if the result we got was real or not.

Comment: Hard to believe that host providers can affect the operation of MySQL. Surely it has more to do with the MySQL configuration?

Comment: But that would be set up by the hosting provider?